# Как из bat файла запустить putty и выполнить команду на сервере?

Tags: ssh, bat, putty

Есть `bat` Файл такого содержания

```
start "putty" "c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\putty.exe" -ssh test.ru:22 -l mylogin -pw mypassword
```

Он работает , запускает Putty и открывает ssh сессию.

Как теперь выполнить команду на сервере? И после выполнения желательно закрыть сессию?

Comment: Переделайте батник на скрипт (скажем, VBS). После запуска putty найдите его окно и шлите туда (sendkeys) нужную последовательность символов.

Comment: Или, если хотите оставаться в формате батника, см., напр., https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050135/10138734

Comment: @Akina Вы как-то сложно придумали, такое пригодиться чтобы например ввести пароль автоматически, мне это не нужно, нужно просто запустить .sh на сервере. Большое спасибо Вам. Все я разобрался сам, создаем txt файл например command.txt c командами которые надо выполнить. И добавляем ключ -m в команду start "putty" "c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\putty.exe" -ssh test.ru:22 -l mylogin -pw mypassword -m command.txt и все работает

Comment: Откуда я знаю, что именно Вы желаете вводить? я описываю наиболее общий вариант, подходящий практически для любого случая. Вот если бы Вы описывали задачу подробнее - возможно, Вы сразу бы получили ответ для именно Вашего случая.

Comment: @Akina Да все в порядке, я и сам разобрался , и за Ваш ответ спасибо. Он мне тоже пригодиться. Мне и был интересен общий случай

Comment: А винда случаем не 10?

Comment: @donRumata да windows 10. Все работает

Comment: Дык там же есть родной openbsd-шный ssh. Зачем путти?